# Unable to duplicate a visual query

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Whenever I try to duplicate a visual query, I get a status 400 error:

> Had an error talking to the server (status 400).
>   Message: Bad Request
>   Detail: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in 08.04.06. It's already fixed https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/844 and will be release either today or Monday.

Comment: Just released 08.04.07 pre-release - should be final, but we like to use it on a few sites before we give the final ok, but you should be able to just go ahead.